# JavaScript scrolllock

Tags: javascript

Нужен скрипт по фризу скролла. Человек скролит, попадает на блок, смотрит 5 слайдов блока, фриз уходит. Далее если прокручиваем назад происходит тоже самое. Придумал пока-что только как зафризить, как отфризить и потом задать опять фриз никак не идёт в голову. Вот код того что я сделал пока-что, кстати еще нужно чтобы отфриз происходил от того что в одном элементе будет не class="list-item" а class="list-item active"

Comment: let check = true;
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
if(window.pageYOffset > 950 && window.pageYOffset < 1050 && check === true) {
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
scrollTo(0, 1000);

}
}
)

Comment: для этого есть специальные либы, поищите просто